# Electron, React and WebSockets causes WebSocket.Server is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, websocket, electron

I am working on a new project to learn Electron and React and I'm hitting a problem when I am trying to start a web socket as a server.

I have the following code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
        const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 8080});

        wss.on('connection', function connection(ws){
            ws.on('message', function incoming(message){
                console.log("Received: %s", message);
            });

            ws.send("hello");
        });
```

But when I run it I get the error:

> TypeError: WebSocket.Server is not a constructor

Every example on the WS repository seems to throw some odd errors and not able to find anything relevant with what I'm using. I'm using the repository from https://github.com/websockets/ws.

**UPDATE**

Below is the main process (start.js)

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        },
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL ||
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../public/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        })
    )

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

Below is the render script (index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './App.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


class StatusBar extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            running: false
        }
    }

    handleStartStopClick()
    {
        if (this.state.running)
        {
            this.stopProxy();
        }
        else
        {
            this.startProxy();
        }
    }

    startProxy()
    {
        const WebSocket = require('ws');
        const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 8080});

        wss.on('connection', function connection(ws){
            ws.on('message', function incoming(message){
                console.log("Received: %s", message);
            });

            ws.send("hello");
        });
    }

    stopProxy()
    {
        this.setState({running: false});
    }

    render() {
        let status = this.state.running ? "Stop Proxy" : "Start Proxy";
        return (

            <div className="status_bar">
                <button onClick={() => {this.handleStartStopClick()}}>
                    {status}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<StatusBar />, document.getElementById("status_bar"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is that there are native `WebSocket` API in chromium. You can see on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) and is has no member called Server. Therefore, when use it on render process, the required `WebSocket` lib will be overwrite by native.
If you `console.log` the required `WebSocket`, it will show that

```js
f () {
  throw new Error(
    'ws does not work in browser. Browser clients must use the native ' + 'WebSocket object'
  );
}
```

Comment: Did anyone come to a solution then to use ws on the front end?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine when run in Node.js without Electron (provided the `ws` module is installed).

The error you're seeing is likely caused by two overlapping APIs that provide the WebSocket object. It looks like you're running this code in the renderer process, where the `WebSocket` object is already defined as part of the JavaScript API (offering a WebSocket client).

The `WebSocket.Server` constructor is provided by the `ws` module, which seems not to be loaded in your case.

If you run the WebSocket server in the renderer process, make sure that `nodeIntegration` is set to `true` for the corresponding BrowserWindow. Only then, using `require` to load Node.js modules works:

```js
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow( {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    },
});
```

If you want to read up on the differences between the main and the renderer process in Electron, check this out: [Main and Renderer Processes](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes).

Comment: Thanks, I've read up on that link you sent and you're right in that I am attempting to start the socket in the render thread I believe. I've tried adding the `nodeIntegration: true` but doesn't seem to have had any affect

Comment: I sometimes forget the `webPreferences` part when adding `nodeIntegration`. Can you confirm it's in your code? I've tried running the WebSocket in the renderer process and it works. Can you add your (minimal) main process code to your question? And also the renderer code.

Comment: Yep, I've got the webPreferences object as part of the nodeIntegration. I've added a version of my render script and main process script to the question

Comment: Might be related to webpack: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1538

Comment: I don't think I'm using webpack - unless node.js/electron/react installs it by default, is there a way to find out for sure. I don't seem to have any webpack config files that I can see